# How to Transfer unknown data array to webview using json in android

Tags: javascript, android, json, arraylist, android-webview

I am getting a array from cursor, I want to pass the array to webview for display as chart. I don't have any experience in Json can you help.

For Conversion to Json

```
  @JavascriptInterface
      public JSONArray getNum11() {
                JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(mArrayList));
                return myArray;
      }
```

Reconversion to Array

```
  var xval = JSON.parse(androidvalues.getNum11());
```

Comment: Yeah..Post some code first.

Comment: I am using example from this, but going no where, what is the method to convert array to json array and again back to array in webview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114993/how-to-pass-json-formatted-data-from-a-webview-to-a-html-page

Comment: Its a simple example. Post code where you're getting trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Json with Array is a huge challenge. Every example you can come across has some fixed data, mostly strings getting passed and parsed. Now getting a dynamically generated data array to be passed from Android activity to Webview is huge challenge. Now due to paucity of time. I have gone to not so good looking but workable model provided in example.

[Android Cookbook
*A Crowd-sourced Cookbook on Writing Great Android® Apps*](https://github.com/IanDarwin/Android-Cookbook-Examples/commit/96d753fc0d920fb64a789ba93ea9143a396b5582)

Kudos to this guy.